# 7z | extract to same folder as archive

Tags: debian, 7-zip

How can I get 7z to extract the contents of a rar archive to the folder where it found the files?

I tried this and it just extracts to whichever folder I have my session in:

```
find ./ -name '*.rar' -exec 7z x -r {} \;
```

I want it to recurse through a set of folders and extract archives to the folder(s) where it found the archive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to have 'find' change the "current" directory to where *it* found the files, before running 7z.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[e (Extract) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm):

> Extracts files from an archive to the current directory or to the
> output directory. The output directory can be specified by -o (Set
> Output Directory) switch.
>
> This command copies all extracted files to one directory. If you want
> extract files with full paths, you must use x (Extract with full
> paths) command.

Example : To extract all files from archive `archive.zip` to the
current directory

```
7z e archive.zip
```